# PHP: preg_match_all - anyway to capture offset and use the PREG_SET_ORDER flag?

Tags: php

I need to part out the matches in a more intuitive manner than preg_Set_order gives while still getting the offset of each match. Is there anyways to accomplish this?

I need to capture what kind of tag and do not want to post process the capture. Lookbehind is just a mess.

This will get all the tags and there offset but always pops out a 3-dim array which is excessive:

```
preg_match_all('|(?<=<)[\/a-zA-Z]+|',$file,$matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

This yields a much cleaner result but I dont know the offset where the tags are located:

```
preg_match_all('|<(\/*)([a-zA-Z]+)[^>]*>|',$file,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER)
```

So what I need is a combination of the two:

```
preg_match_all('|<(\/*)([a-zA-Z]+)[^>]*>|',$file,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking. Please show some sample code containing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you're looking for, but it appears you're trying to use PREG_SET_ORDER while still getting offsets?

If so, just pass both flags to preg_match_all:

```
preg_match_all($find, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER|PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
var_dump($matches)
```

Numerical flags such as these can be combined using the bit OR operator | (vertical pipe).

Comment: HAHAHA this is exactly what I wanted. I had no idea how to pass multiple flags.